# Why am i not able to print variable value directly in main method which is declared in class above main method?

Tags: java

**Why static variable value been allowed to print directly in main method, while to print normal integer type value, it requires to creation of object.**

- although that is global, but x is also being accessed in same class then why i can't directly access that.

While answering,  please cover memory allocation part.

From my understanding

> static, as it is global variable stored on permanent generation, then what about this primitive int x, is this not allocated on private stack? Please assist.

```
  public class Test{

    int x = 7;
    static int y = 10;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("the value of y "+ y);

        //compile error on sysout for value x like this,
        //System.out.println("the value of x "+ x);

       //While in this way i am able to print x, why?

        Test test= new Test();
        System.out.println("the value of x "+test.x);

    }

}
```

***Please assist on memory allocation of program, Thanks in advance!***

Comment: `x` is a member of an *instance* - each `Test` object has its own `x`, while `y` is shared between all of them

Comment: Please go and revisit the concept of `static keyword`

Comment: @utkarsh31 `static` isn't an operator, it's a keyword.

Comment: I recommend you work through some basic Java tutorials before posting to SO.

Comment: Dear friends, Thanks for yr recomm. i tried to find on few forums, but i am not clear with the memory allocation areas for x, and then i planned to posted.

Comment: thanks UnholySheep

Answer (score 0):

The [`static` modifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1) on a field means that that field is shared by the entire class, not just specific instances. Without `static`, the field is part of *instances* of the class (created with `new`).

Your `main` method, also `static`, is run without any insance of the class. So it has access to class fields (aka "class variables") declared with `static`, but since it doesn't have an instance, it can't access instance fields (aka "instance variables").

`Test test = new Test();` creates an instance, which you're referencing from the `test` variable. That instance has a field, `x`, and so you can access it.

In terms of memory allocation:

- Memory for the class and various other classes will be allocated by the JVM when starting up your program so it can call `main` (allocating memory for the `Test` class includes a small bit for `y`).
- Within `main`, you're allocating memory for an instance of `Test` via `new Test` (which includes a small bit of memory for `x`).